# Opensmile: unreadable csv file while extracting prosody features from wav file

Tags: csv, audio, feature-extraction, audeering-opensmile

I am extracting prosody features from an audio file while using Opensmile using Windows version of Opensmile. It runs successful and an output csv is generated. But when I open csv, it shows some rows that are not readable. I used this command to extract prosody feature:

```
SMILEXtract  -C \opensmile-3.0-win-x64\config\prosody\prosodyShs.conf -I audio_sample_01.wav -O prosody_sample1.csv
```

And the output of csv looks like this:

[[image: output of above mentioned command for prosody deatures1]

Even I tried to use the sample wave file given in Example audio folder  given in opensmile  directory and the output is same (not readable). Can someone help me in identifying where the problem is actually? and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

You need to enable the csvSink component in the configuration file to make it work. The file `config\prosody\prosodyShs.conf` that you are using does not have this component defined and always writes binary output.

You can verify that it is the standart binary output in this way: omit the `-O` parameter from your command so it becomes`SMILEXtract -C \opensmile-3.0-win-x64\config\prosody\prosodyShs.conf -I audio_sample_01.wav` and execute it. You will get a `output.htk` file which is exactly the same as the `prosody_sample1.csv`.

How output csv? You can take a look at the example configuration in `opensmile-3.0-win-x64\config\demo\demo1_energy.conf` where a `csvSink` component is defined.

You can find more information in the official documentation:

- [Get started](https://audeering.github.io/opensmile/get-started.html) page of the openSMILE documentation
- The section on [configuration files](https://audeering.github.io/opensmile/reference.html#configuration-files)
- Documentation for [cCsvSink](https://audeering.github.io/opensmile/_components/cCsvSink.html#ccsvsink)

Answer (score 1):

This is how I solved the issue. First I added the csvSink component to the list of the component instances. `instance[csvSink].type = cCsvSink`

Next I added the configuration parameters for this instance.

```
[csvSink:cCsvSink]
reader.dmLevel = energy
filename = \cm[outputfile(O){output.csv}:file name of the output CSV 
file]
delimChar = ;
append = 0
timestamp = 1
number = 1
printHeader = 1
\{../shared/standard_data_output_lldonly.conf.inc}`
```

Now if you run this file it will throw you errors because `reader.dmLevel = energy` is dependent on waveframes. So the final changes would be:

```
[energy:cEnergy]
reader.dmLevel = waveframes
writer.dmLevel = energy

[int:cIntensity]
reader.dmLevel = waveframes

[framer:cFramer]
reader.dmLevel=wave
writer.dmLevel=waveframes
```

[Further reference](https://www.programmersought.com/article/6531221875/) on how to configure opensmile configuration files can be found here

Comment: Hello @Moody I want to extract features using opensmile tool, for example I use this command:
`SMILExtract -C config/demo/demo1_energy.conf -I example-audio/opensmile.wav -O opensmile.energy.csv`

the problem here is, in the input you can enter one audio file, but in my case I have a folder contain 1000 audio files, is there a possibility to extract features of all audio files in the folder and generate one (.csv) file for all audio files ?

Comment: I would do it in python like this: 

`import os`
`for each in allFiles:
    name = each.replace('Desktop/all_files','').replace('.wav','')
    os.system("SMILExtract -C config/demo/demo1_energy.conf -I " + each + " -O folder_to_save/file_"+name+".csv")`